# stream is null on GetManifestResourceStream for groupdocs.total

Tags: c#, stream, .net-assembly, groupdocs

I already googled about my problem but sadly I am not able to succeed.

So I have many desktop application in which I am using groupdocs.total product,

so what I usually do is I paste my `.lic` file in my root folder and in my program.cs file on start function I execute the below line of code

```
var appAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "DocProScan.GroupDocs.Total.lic";//DocProScan is my project name
using (Stream stream = appAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    GroupDocs.Viewer.License licViewer = new GroupDocs.Viewer.License();
    licViewer.SetLicense(stream);
}
```

and I set my license like above,

but now I created another desktop application called ScanConsoleApplication this is a desktop console application and I did the same here, I paste the `.lic` file in the root directory and executed the below code

```
var appAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "ScanConsoleApplication.GroupDocs.Total.lic"; //ScanConsoleApplication is my project name
using (Stream stream = appAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    GroupDocs.Viewer.License licViewer = new GroupDocs.Viewer.License();
    licViewer.SetLicense(stream);
}
```

now in the above line of code my stream is coming null.

I don't understand what I miss here.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to diagnose your issue is to list all available manifest resources with `appAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` and see if you have a typo in your  resource name.

Also make sure that you are properly including your license file in your project file (.csproj) with an `EmbeddedResource` item.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="GroupDocs.Total.lic" />
</ItemGroup>
```